# SSRS Expression to extract all Names in an Name Field

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have a query that pulls three fields, over 9000 rows (A-Z, names):

[image]

I am trying to extract by all "A" name Agencies, "B", and so on into Excel worksheets by each A,B,C,etc., once we render and save the report.

Can someone help with an Expression that will accomplish this?

Thanks,
jer

Answer (score 0):

First create a calculated field in the dataset to get the first letter of each agency.

```
=Left(Fields!AgencyName.Value, 1)
```

Next, set up a table (aka tablix or matrix) with two row groups. The parent group should be sorted and grouped by the new `FirstLetter` column. In this group's properties, set it to break at the end of each group. Also set the `PageName` property to be the `FirstLetter`.

The child row group should be grouped by nothing so that it will show every detail row. Sort it by Agency name if desired.

What you should get now is a page for each letter and within each page a row for each agency. When you export to Excel it will create a sheet for each "page" and name them all accordingly.

[image]